# How to effectively disable Dark Mode theming in Nativescript?

Tags: ios, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I tried to add

```
<key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key>
   <string>Light</string>
```

to App_Resources/iOS/Info.plist

But the app still is with dark mode, even after rebuilding it and deleting hooks, node_modules and platforms.

I'm using `tns preview --bundle`.

Comment: With {N} theme you can switch between modes easily.

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but is this supposed to reverse all the colors for me automatically or do I still have to code out all the dark mode styles by hand?

Answer (score 12):

Not sure what can be happening with your code but it is really supposed to work. I have been using it until last update (when we finally had time to handle dark  mode).

You should also be able to force light mode with

```
import Theme from "@nativescript/theme";

Theme.setMode(Theme.Light);
```

Source: https://github.com/NativeScript/theme

Comment: I would set this inside app.js? App.vue?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply here, in your main.js. The file where the app is loaded with New Vue({...}).$start();

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't resolved... The dark mode is still being displayed.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the plist I did (with Nativescript theme installed)

```
Page class="ns-light"
```

Worked for me on iOS 13.1

Comment: I need to add this in each Page of my app?

Comment: no you can do it on frame, 

`template: '
        <Frame class="ns-light">
            <Home />
        </Frame>'
`

please refer to my discussion about this on the theme page here:
https://github.com/NativeScript/theme/issues/244
And please if this worked for you mark the answer with a checkmark :)

Comment: I wish it worked for me. But it didn't. :(
I really don't know what is happenning.
Maybe I'll need to refactor the Nativescript-Theme of this app to try to fix this.

Comment: Can you edit your original question to include:
tns doctor
app.scss
package.json
Information, I'm suspecting either your theme or ios tools or something is not updated to the certain version this stopped being a bug.

Answer (score 0):

put into AppDelegate

```
self.window?.backgroundColor = .white
            if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
                self.window?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
            }
```